# Run Commands in Sequence

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run powershell in sequence. I have following snippet.

```
$TestdevlandingStorageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "Test_Storage" -AccountName "Testdevlanding";
$TestuatlandingStorageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "Test_Storage" -AccountName "Testuatlanding";

Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName "MyOrgTest" -ObjectId $TestdevlandingStorageAccount.Identity.PrincipalId -PermissionsToKeys wrapkey,unwrapkey,get;
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName "MyOrgTest" -ObjectId $TestuatlandingStorageAccount.Identity.PrincipalId -PermissionsToKeys wrapkey,unwrapkey,get;
```

I am getting below error while executing above mentioned command (**First `Set` command runs successfully**):

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ObjectId'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the 
command again.
At C:SomePath\PowerShellStorageEncryption.ps1:27 char:71
+ ... " -ObjectId $TestprodpublishedStorageAccount.Identity.PrincipalId -P ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.SetAzureKeyVaultAccessPolicy
```

If I run just one group operation, then it would execute fine:

```
$TestdevlandingStorageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "Test_Storage" -AccountName "Testdevlanding";
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName "HoneywellTest" -ObjectId $TestdevlandingStorageAccount.Identity.PrincipalId -PermissionsToKeys wrapkey,unwrapkey,get;
```

I tried searching on Google on *How to run powershell commands in sequence*, most of the answers suggested to use `;` which I am using now without any luck.

Can someone please suggest what I could be missing?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ObjectId'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the 
>   command again.`

Means that the `PrincipalId` was empty so maybe the original `Get-AzureRmStorageAccount` didn't find a storage account. But also make sure that you don't just have a typo.

> `-ObjectId $aTestuatpublishedStorageAccount.Identity.PrincipalId`

The `$[a]TestuatpublishedStorageAccount` in your name doesn't reflect the other variable names you used.

Try:

```
$TestdevlandingStorageAccount = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "Test_Storage" -AccountName "Testdevlanding").Identity.PrincipalId;
$TestuatlandingStorageAccount = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "Test_Storage" -AccountName "Testuatlanding").Identity.PrincipalId;

Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName "HoneywellTest" -ObjectId $TestdevlandingStorageAccount -PermissionsToKeys wrapkey,unwrapkey,get;
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName "HoneywellTest" -ObjectId $TestuatlandingStorageAccount -PermissionsToKeys wrapkey,unwrapkey,get;
```

To verify that you are actually getting a PrincipalId you can just run these:

```
$TestdevlandingStorageAccount = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "Test_Storage" -AccountName "Testdevlanding").Identity.PrincipalId;
$TestuatlandingStorageAccount = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "Test_Storage" -AccountName "Testuatlanding").Identity.PrincipalId;

$TestdevlandingStorageAccount
$TestuatlandingStorageAccount
```

Comment: That's not the reason. If I run command one by one or in two sets (get and set, get and set), it works without any errors.

Comment: And, all my variables are valid object. I mean, its not null. I verified that.

Comment: @shashwat Then I'd suggest that there is context being lost between the two commands. My suggestion above is to get the principalid straight away.

Answer (score 0):

I notice the errormessage is showing a variable name that is incorrect:

```
-ObjectId $aTestuatpublishedStorageAccount.Identity.PrincipalId
```

while in your snippet you use `$TestuatlandingStorageAccount`

Did you perhaps make a typo the first time you ran the code?
Bernie White has the correct answer i think.

Comment: I am using correct variable names. That was a typo I made while I was changing variable names before posting (just to protect original names)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue,

Not all my storage accounts had identity assigned to them. I assigned identity to all my storage accounts using below command and then I could run command successfully.

```
Set-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -AccountName "mystorageaccount" -AssignIdentity
```

Really sorry guys! I simply assumed that there could be issue because of sequence. I tried deleting the question but not able to.

Many thanks to all of you who responded to my question.